# Unresolved Reference getProperty

Tags: kotlin, properties-file, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to load a property from my `local.properties` file in my `build.gradle.kts` like this:

```
val properties = Properties().load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").inputStream())
val key: String = properties.getProperty("key")
```

But I get the following error:

> e: /build.gradle.kts:37:30: Unresolved reference: getProperty

Why is that happening? It can find the class Properties from `java.util.Properties`, but not the function `getProperty`. That doesn't make any sense to me. How can I resolve this?

This is the whole build file:

Full build.gradle.kts file:

```
import java.util.Properties

plugins {
    kotlin("js") version "1.5.20"
}

group = "de.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(npm("obsidian", "0.12.5", false))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-js:1.5.1")
}

kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        binaries.executable()
        browser {
            useCommonJs()
            webpackTask {
                output.libraryTarget = "commonjs"
                output.library = null
                outputFileName = "main.js"
            }
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}

val properties = Properties().load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").inputStream())
val key: String = properties.getProperty("key")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` method of `Properties` class returns `void`, so your `val properties` is `kotlin.Unit`.

To get desired result, you need to initialize `properties` in the following way:

```kotlin
val properties = Properties().apply { load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").inputStream()) }
```

Anyway, that's not a recommended way to pass configuration properties into Gradle build script (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)

Comment: What would you suggest? The property is needed for most gradle commands, device specific and project specific. As I use it in every command I'll be annoyed to pass it as property every time, and as it is device specific I don't want to check it into git. As it is project specific the user global gradle properties also seems wrong.

Comment: Option 1: Place all project-specific properties in `gradle.properties` file in the project directory (and commit it to git). Place all device-specific properties in `gradle.properties` in the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` directory or define environment variables with the `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_` prefix (they will take precedence over declared in `gradle.properties` in the project directory). You may add some additional prefix to indicate what exact project they are related to (and avoid properties name clashing among various projects).

Comment: Option 2: Place all project-specific properties in `gradle.properties` file in project directory (and commit it to git), then disable tracking file changes for `gradle.properties` on your device (`git update-index --skip-worktree gradle.properties`) and replace them with device-specific.

Comment: Thank you for solving my original problem. I am not convinced that using the user home gradle file or not tracking the gradle.properties is a good idea, but I will look into it.